# Issue with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I don't know why but my dropdown doesn't work correctly. As you will see, the browser cuts the dropdown, the blue box is the issue. What can i do to fix it? I need to add some css? The photo shows the issue, I think with css the issue will dissapear but I dont know. Maybe I need to change something with the bootstrap. I dont wrote something strange, the only thing that I change was the background color and I add the buttons next to the dropdown  menu.

[photoNavbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boYLH.png)

My code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #b4474c;">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="index.php">Base de Datos</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">test</span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-1" id="navbarNavDropdown" style="color: #FFF;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="index.php"><i class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></i> Inicio <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-kanban"></i>
                        Proyectos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver Informes</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-people"></i>
                        Recursos Humanos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Todos los recursos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Asignados a Proyectos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Asignados a Becas</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i
                            class="bi bi-cash-coin"></i>
                        Presupuesto
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Asignar Presupuesto</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-book"></i>
                        Publicaciones
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver Publicaciones</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-calendar"></i>
                        Eventos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver Eventos</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i> Configuración <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse order-3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                        Perfil
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: black;"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
                            Ajustes</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: black;"><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i>
                            Salir</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include a [mcve] to your question.  Adding only an image only is not helpful [Read Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: I edit my post!

Comment: The issue cannot be reproduced with the code provided.

Comment: I edit my post!

Answer (score 0):

The `dropdown-menu` class has the property `left: 0`, which causes this situation. I added an auxiliary class with the following values.

```
.clearLeft
{
  right:-16px !important;
  left:auto !important;
}
```

This property class is `left: 0;` Clears and adjusts the menu on the right

---

```css
.clearLeft
{
  right:-16px !important;
  left:auto !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<!-- CSS only -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #b4474c;">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="index.php">Base de Datos</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">test</span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-1" id="navbarNavDropdown" style="color: #FFF;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="index.php"><i class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></i> Inicio <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-kanban"></i>
                        Proyectos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver Informes</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-people"></i>
                        Recursos Humanos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Todos los recursos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Asignados a Proyectos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Asignados a Becas</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i
                            class="bi bi-cash-coin"></i>
                        Presupuesto
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Asignar Presupuesto</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-book"></i>
                        Publicaciones
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver Publicaciones</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-calendar"></i>
                        Eventos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver Eventos</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i> Configuración <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse order-3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                        Perfil
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu clearLeft" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-color: #b4474c;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: black;"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
                            Ajustes</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: black;"><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i>
                            Salir</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```